# "Wear and tear is" or "wear and tear are"

Tags: word-usage

I just wrote the following sentence:

> Normal wear and tear **is** not considered damage to the property.

MS Word suggested that I change the sentence to:

> Normal wear and tear **are** not considered damage to the property.

I think that Word understands wear and tear to be a list of things, but I think wear and tear is considered as one "thing". Which one is actually correct, and why? Or might both actually work?

Comment: It's one thing, because if an article is just worn, we file that under *wear and tear*, just as we do if it is just torn. The expression means *damage or deterioration resulting from normal use*, so it refers to a category of damage exemplified by *wear* and *tear*, and is not a list of two distinct types of damage.

Comment: @Minty - with a citation, that'd be a good answer.

Comment: _Basic research is required._ It's simple to google "wear and tear"; [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wear-and-tear) gives examples using both singular and plural verb-forms, while [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wear-and-tear), [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_and_tear), and most relevant hits on the basic Google search use singular agreement. 'Wear and tear' is usually taken as a fixed phrase, or even an open compound.

Comment: It can be whichever you want it to be. You are the person who is assigning the phrase meaning. *Most* people would consider it to be a single thing, because that's generally how it's used. But I can easily think of a (possibly contrived) context where they would be treated as distinct things.

Comment: @JasonBassford agreed - for example, "wear and tear are two different things".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wear-and-tear), "wear and tear" is an uncountable noun, which means it can't take a plural. In fact, the "learner's definition" even uses the word "is":

> Wear and tear is the damage or change that is caused to something when it is being used normally.

Comment: But a good answer would look at far more than a single reference. This gives far from a complete picture.